# Trigger for not updating and delete data

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table tblDHColl with fields ProjectID, HoleID, X, Y, Z and Locked (bit datatype). I want to create a trigger to prevent any update or delete for the holes where Locked=1 or 'True'. I want to allow any other updations or deletions of the data if Locked field is 0 or 'false' for any hole.
Since I am new to triggers, please advise me how to create a trigger on tblDHColl.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_utblDHCollRollBack] ON [dbo].[tblDHColl] 
FOR UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM deleted d 
        INNER JOIN tbldhcoll c ON d.DataSet = c.DataSet AND d.Hole_ID = c.Hole_ID 
        where locked=1
    ) AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM inserted i 
        INNER JOIN tbldhcoll c ON i.DataSet = c.DataSet AND i.Hole_ID = c.Hole_ID 
        where locked=1
    ) 
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR('ERROR: Validated data cannot be modified',16,-1) 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
        RETURN 
    END 
GO 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDHColl] ENABLE TRIGGER [TR_utblDHCollRollBack] GO
```

Kind Regards,
Dinesh

Comment: Please post a snippet on the trigger code you have so far, it is hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: Please specify your dbs.  Trigger creation differs from db to db

Comment: @dns_nx, that page is useless... Poor, proprietary examples make no good at all.

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL Database and HoleID in the table is primary key. CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_utblDHCollRollBack] ON [dbo].[tblDHColl]
FOR UPDATE, DELETE
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted d INNER JOIN  tbldhcoll c ON d.DataSet = c.DataSet AND d.Hole_ID = c.Hole_ID where locked=1)
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted i INNER JOIN tbldhcoll c ON i.DataSet = c.DataSet AND i.Hole_ID = c.Hole_ID where locked=1)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('ERROR: Validated data cannot be modified',16,-1)
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 RETURN
END

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDHColl] ENABLE TRIGGER [TR_utblDHCollRollBack]
GO

Comment: please edit your question and put the new info in your question, not in a comment. It is to hard to read here

Comment: For multi-row deletes or updates which are a mixture of locked and non-locked rows, what should happen? Should the non-locked rows still be deleted/updated? (In which case, raising an error is problematic, but it's worth being explicit on whether you've considered this scenario)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the logic of deleting or updating records, you should use an "instead of" trigger. It will be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_utblDHCollRollBack] ON [dbo].[tblDHColl] 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN

    DECLARE @Count  INT
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM inserted

    IF @Count > 0 -- This is UPDATE

    BEGIN   

        UPDATE c
        SET
        Field1 = i.Field1,
        Field2 = i.Field2,
        /*
        .
        .
        .
        */
        FieldN = i.FieldN
        FROM deleted d 
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.Hole_ID = d.Hole_ID
        INNER JOIN tbldhcoll c ON d.DataSet = c.DataSet AND d.Hole_ID = c.Hole_ID 
        where ISNULL(d.locked, 0) != 1
    END

    ELSE 

    BEGIN   

        DELETE c        
        FROM deleted d 
        INNER JOIN tbldhcoll c ON d.DataSet = c.DataSet AND d.Hole_ID = c.Hole_ID 
        where ISNULL(d.locked, 0) != 1

    END
GO
```